# Android within OnClickListener, update image part way through method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an OnClickListener for images, that invokes a method which updates an image using the code:

```
iView.setImageResource(resID);
```

This turns over a card so that it is visible. Within the same method, I want to turn the card back over after 1-2 seconds, so that it is not visible again. The card is only redrawn after the OnClickListener finishes executing, so all the User sees is the back of the card still. How can I show the User the front of the card for 1-2 seconds within this method call?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `Handler`.

Like this:

```
// Flip to second image
imageView.setImageResource(resID);

// Millis
long END_IN_MS = 2000; // 2 seconds

// This will get called 2 seconds later
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Flip back to first image
        imageView.setImageResource(OLD_RES_ID);
    }
}, END_IN_MS);
```